# give jquery a value from a ZK timer ( or label)

Tags: javascript, jquery, zk, zk-grid

hello everything i am working on a zk project and i need to send the value of "delay" of a timer to a Jquery fonction , i tried to use EL , but it s not seem to work with me , here is my code , can u help me pls? ( i have no experience in jquery )

```
<zk>
<html>
     <div id="countdown1"></div><br></br>
     <label  id="here" >${refreshTimer.deplay}</label>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery.timeTo.min.js"></script>
     <script>

               $('#countdown1').timeTo({
                    seconds: Number($('#here').text())/10000,// i want to insert a the delay of timer here.
                    theme: "black",
                    fontSize: 20
                });
                 </script>
            </html>

</zk>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try it, but as far as I remember, I have the same issue with this until I change `$('#here').text()` with `$('#here').val()`